# Are ListBox.Items and ListBox.SelectedItems linked?

Tags: c#, winforms, enumeration

I'm working on a WinForms project, on which there is a `TextBox` where the user can input a search query, and a `ListBox` where all items are visible and matched items highlighted.

When I'm iterating through `ListBox.Items` and modifying `ListBox.SelectedItems`, I get an `InvalidOperationException: List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.`

Here's the code

```
private void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox.ClearSelected();

    foreach (var item in listBox.Items) // Exception happens here...
    {
        if (item.ToString().Contains(SearchTextBox.Text))
            listBox.SelectedItems.Add(item); // ... but I'm not modifying listBox.Items
    }
}
```

I've already thought of a better solution, but I would still like to know why the exception happened.

**Is there some kind of link between `ListBox.Items` and `ListBox.SelectedItems`, or why does modifying one, make enumerating through the other impossible?**

Comment: In my experience the SelectedItems are set by the built-in events for selecting items with the mouse by click.
Have you tried to select items by yourListBox.SetSelected(yourIndexToSelect); ?

Comment: afaik it should work with a normal for loop, but i have not yet done this with listbox. you can use @michael's attempt then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [MSDN ListBox.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx),
 <del>you would want to add items through the following code:</del>

> listbox.Items.Add();

EDIT: (I meant to add the following after rereading the ? but my laptop turned off due to low battery)

```
   listBox1.SetSelected(<index>, true);
   listBox1.SetSelected(<index>, true);
   listBox1.SetSelected(<index>, true);
```

Comment: @MD.Unicorn Thanks was modifying my question to reflect the above edit and laptop died :/

Answer (score 0):

Items are not just the objects in the ListBox but also its state like the selected state. So you need to use a loop without an Enumerator to change the state of an item regardless of the way you change the state. Makes no difference if you use SelectedItems, SelectedIndices,  SetSelected or whatever.